# how to type an array argument of any array?

Tags: typescript

I wonder how functions like map and filter give you type hints although they take any array as an argument. How do I correctly type this function here?

```
function utils_process_sequential(array:any[], task:(item:any) => any):Promise<any[]>{ return new Promise(async (rs, rj) => {

        const result:any[] = []

        async function next(index:number = 0):Promise<void>{

            try {

                const res = await task(array[index])

                res !== undefined && result.push(res)

                index < array.length - 1 ? await next(++index) : rs(result)
            }

            catch (err){

                rj({error: 'utils_process_sequential', message: 'error processing task'})
            }
        }

        array.length ? await next() : rs([])
})}
```

Comment: is it expected that `task` returns `void`?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mqxJ2N) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: task can also return anything

Comment: Okay, does [this one](https://tsplay.dev/w29G8W) work then?

Comment: it does work. I haven't worked with generic types yet. thank you

Comment: Okay, will write an answer soon. Please, make sure that `task` doesn't return `void` in your code, it doesn't make sense, since you assign its return value to the `res`

Comment: ok changed it to "any"

Comment: `utils_process_sequential<number, string>(array: number[], task: (item: number) => string): Promise<string[]>` the editor does show all the types correctly, generics are very helpful. thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way `map`, `filter` array methods works, is by using [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).

Official type definition of `map`:

```
interface Array<T> {
   map<U>(callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => U, thisArg?: any): U[];
}
```

As you can see we have two generic parameters:
`T` - type of the array's elements
`U` - return type of the mapper function

We should apply the same logic to your function, which is pretty similar to `map`. As I understood you return a promise of an array of elements that are typed by the `task` function's return type, which is mapper in the case of `map`.

```
function utils_process_sequential<T, R>(
  array: T[],
  task: (item: T) => R,
): Promise<R[]> {
  return new Promise(async (rs, rj) => {
    const result: R[] = [];

    async function next(index: number = 0): Promise<void> {
      try {
        const res = await task(array[index]);

        res !== undefined && result.push(res);

        index < array.length - 1 ? await next(++index) : rs(result);
      } catch (err) {
        rj({
          error: 'utils_process_sequential',
          message: 'error processing task',
        });
      }
    }

    array.length ? await next() : rs([]);
  });
}
```

Testing:

```
const arr: (string | number)[] = [];

// Promise<string[]>
const result = utils_process_sequential(arr, (item) => 'string');
```

[Link to Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABCWAbAzgfQA4Cc4QCm6W6hAjiIWLAIaoA8AKgDSIBKAfABQBQiiWrly0AngC5ETANoBdFv0RRa6ANaTuMKIQC2kpgEpEAXk4cFByQAV8OmGQbs5ZgN6LchKCFxIwhAO6INnB2ZNwqopCI3LjobLgAVkamiG4CAhAI6FCIHuggqFCSTrImiHIA3LyKAhFRoJCwCIh+AB5QmmAAJoStkmAgOgBGhLhlAAyWQbb2hAwAbnAwXa416VC4oqlr6YiZYNm5xGW0-rRaSiqq4cJi0jDdvbIGVTvpeYgAhMbGyI-AD0IXUQADIQUd8oUAHTYEDoAAWMWIL2qu12Dx6rUQDEEt1EUNQ1AA5lB4YgALSIACMiAA-IIzhc2h0ANQsjG9IySWJIyFQFFoxAAXz2tCgEDJ3FGuCMaUFuQS3Dl8sQ0rguEkAHIUDAMDh8EQSJgyJRqHRUJqFCqBDpiOhaETCFq1WM8AQ7Q8iZc1Ja3gIhQK0UK1sG1kIRPjCWASWT6adzjlmdwubl0Nw5IGA1VQ-tDuGNNlcJ7EAAfFqDEYyuRlSrVAD0demIVmDELnucvFzOTyBRyvx1erdhtIFCoNBg9BuuDYmm0OmSZk1bejmpRQA)